# node: bad option: --experimental-report

Tags: node.js

https://nodejs.org/api/report.html#report_usage

https://nodesource.com/blog/experimental-features-in-node.js/

Running "node --experimental-report" at the command line is suppose to enable the process.report API...  Open Google Cloud Shell from console.cloud.google.com which has NodeJS version v10.14.2 pre-installed...

node --experimental-report --report-uncaught-exception --report-on-signal --report-on-fatalerror

or

node --experimental-report

...

Just expect a normal REPL environment with process.report defined, instead it remains undefined and I'm getting:

node: bad option: --experimental-report

node: bad option: --report-uncaught-exception

node: bad option: --report-on-signal

node: bad option: --report-on-fatalerror

Comment: Node.js [Diagnostic Report](https://nodejs.org/api/report.html), as suggested by the option name, is still experimental and appears to be present only from Node v11.

Answer (score 1):

You got it right. The only thing stopping you from using this feature is the node version **v10.14.2** you are using. This feature is only experimantally available since **v11**, though ideally **v11.7.0** as stated by the author Boneskull himself at [his talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IxETA6wZWlg).